# How can I make a form's controls not load until at least the frame of the form has been displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a C# Winforms form that has a ton of custom controls that take about 10 seconds to load. Right now, when I click the menu item to open my form, the menu freezes for 10 seconds, and then the form just pops up ready to go. What I'd like to do is the following: As soon as you click the appropriate menu item to open up my form, I want to display the form immediately, but perhaps with just a red background and no controls on it. Then the form can start trying to load all my controls. That way the user sees that their mouse click opened the new form, and it doesn't look like the whole app froze. Moving it to a new thread is not an option.

Comment: You could load a "loading" form with an animation that lets the person know it's loading, and then load your form from that form.

Comment: You say "moving it to a new thread is not an option". That is true as you can only have one Ui thread but are there other restrictions in your code that prevent the use of a background thread?

Comment: There already is a perfectly good way to provide proper feedback in this case.  It is a one-liner: `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your user controls in a seperate user control, then instantiate it in your Shown event and then add it to your form.

i.e. something like this

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl1 usr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        usr = new UserControl1();
        usr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel1.Controls.Add(usr);
    }
}
```

**UserControl1**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```